# How can I load the http resources by using the require method with webpack

Tags: http, webpack, require

I want to load a http js file by using require with webpack in the js file instead of using script tag in view page, because some necessary things must be configed before the file loading. The code is like following:
require("http://xxxxx");
but it doesn't work with webpack, how can I make this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `require` external files which resides in different location with webpack. You have to use some library like `jQuery` / <strike>`requirejs`</strike> / `script.js` to load the external files.